# Transforming a table ? using pivot / unpivot

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot, unpivot

My brain is hurting!
I want to transform the data in the table generated from the below sql.
The examples of the use of pivot tends to involve summarizing the data. Clearly here I am actually expanding the data.

```
CREATE TABLE GCS 
(
  EYES VARCHAR2(20) 
, VERBAL VARCHAR2(20) 
, MOTOR VARCHAR2(20) 
, UNITNUM VARCHAR2(20) 
);

Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140560');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('3',4,'2','140729');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('1',2,'6','140771');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140502');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',4,'6','140537');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140566');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140571');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140781');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140780');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('3',4,'5','140788');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140585');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140577');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140747');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140778');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140569');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',1,'6','140575');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140779');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140785');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140753');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140786');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140555');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140557');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140554');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140736');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',4,'6','140745');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140783');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140556');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140559');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140574');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140573');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140572');
Insert into GCS ("Eyes","Verbal","Motor",UNITNUM) values ('4',5,'6','140738');
commit;
```

into the following form. I am sure I need to use pivot / unpivot but can't work out how.

```
Item  | Score | Unitnum
----------
Eyes    4   140560
Verbal  5   140560
Motor   6   140560
Eyes    3   140729
Verbal  4   140729
Motor   2   140729
Eyes    1   140771
Verbal  2   140771
Motor   6   140771
```

.....etc

Comment: Pivoting is the process of transforming group 'titles' to columns and aggregating values in those columns. This seems to be the reverse, in a way, although you are not un-aggregating. But why are you storing the data like this and not in a more normalised way? Also, why are you storing numbers as varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is by using **[`Unpivot`](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php#unpivot)** operator

```
select item,
       score,
       unitnum,
from   gcs
       unpivot (score
               for item in(eyes,
                           verbal,
                           motor))
```

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2ad8/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple union to get these values:

```
select 'Eyes' as Item, Eyes, UnitNum
from GCS
union all
select 'Verbal' as Item, Verbal, UnitNum
from GCS
union all
select 'Motor' as Item, Motor, UnitNum
from GCS
```

And you can order by those columns if you need, including the just introduced 'Item':

```
select 'Eyes' as Item, Eyes, UnitNum
from GCS
union all
select 'Verbal' as Item, Verbal, UnitNum
from GCS
union all
select 'Motor' as Item, Motor, UnitNum
from GCS
order by
  unitnum, item
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cca4e/1)